# Editing unnamed EditText inside TextInputLayout throws FrameLayout cannot be cast to EditText error

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-textinputlayout

I made an `EditText` inside a `TextInputLayout` this way:

```
public class Field{
    private Context context;
    private TextInputLayout layo;

    public void build(){
        layo=new TextInputLayout(context);
        layo.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        container.addView(layo);

        final EditText field = new EditText(context); // Crear objeto
        field.setLayoutParams(new TextInputLayout.LayoutParams(TextInputLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,TextInputLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        layo.addView(field);
```

Now, I want to change the text in this "unnamed" EditText (I cna't name it because it could be a different type), so I tried `getChildAt`

```
EditText field = (EditText) layo.getChildAt(0);
field.setText(mytext);
```

It throws this error:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.FrameLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.EditText

I don't know why it finds a FrameLayout inside a TextInputLayout, any idea?

Comment: `TextInputLayout` has an internal structure that consists of more than just what you see. Last I checked, there's at least that one extra `FrameLayout` used to hold a decorator `TextView`, and I wouldn't be surprised if there are more. On top of that, the internals change occasionally, with different versions. Instead of trying to find it yourself with `ViewGroup` methods, you can just use the `getEditText()` method to get a `TextInputLayout`'s `EditText`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll find a [`TextInputLayout.getEditText()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/textfield/TextInputLayout.html#getEditText()) method on `layo` which

> Returns the `EditText` used for text input.

So you could just do

```
EditText field = layo.getEditText();
field.setText(mytext);
```